# C++, can I overload assignment operator of a point of a class?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

It is ok to overload assignment operator of a Class A, but not sure if it is allowed to overload assignment operator of pointer type of class A.
is it legitimate question or not...? If yes, how?

For example, I would like to do ref_count++ whenever we have a pointer reference on it below.

```
class A{
   public:
         A(){}
         ~A(){}
         int ref_count{0};
}

main()
{
        A* a1 = new A();   //line 1
        A* a2 = a1;       //line 2
 }
```

After execution of line 1, A.ref_count is 1
After execution of line 2, A.ref_count is 2

Comment: There is no `operator=()` involved in the two lines in your `main()`

Comment: What you're doing is [*copy initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), not assignment.

Comment: And no you can't overload pointer assignment. The assignment operator *must* be a member function, and when you assign to a pointer it will not be called.

Comment: Fortunately, you don't need to implement ref counting for pointers yourself, in C++ they are spelled `std::shared_ptr<A>`.

Comment: If you want to add more custom code other than just ref-counting, you can write your own wrapper class and overload `operator*` and `operator->` for access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean pointer assignment. Short answer: **no**, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you wan't a reference counted pointer. First lets examine why your solution doesn't work:

1. Here: `A* a1 = new A();` you are doing pointer assignment, *not* class assignment. You cannot overload this operation.
2. In your definition of `Class A` you implement reference counting. This is not a good solution, what if you want a new class (`Class B`) that also requires reference counting? You have to implement it all over again. This is not nice or re-usable.

So, what can we do? Well, it depends on why you wan't reference counting. It seems like you wan't self managed memory. Fortunatley, c++ provides a construct for this already. It is [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). You can use it like this:

```
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> a1 = std::make_shared<A>(); // Reference count is set at 1
  {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a2 = a1; // Reference count is incremented to 2
  } // Reference count is decremented to 1
} // Reference count is decremented to 0 and the memory is released.
```